# Ports of a client get closed while connected through VPN

Tags: vpn

We have clients which we scan through some ports as 445 or 139. It works quite well when they are in our in-house network. But when they are connected through vpn, the ports get closed (cannot connect to them via telnet). Is this a general specification of a vpn connection or can ports be opened manually through a vpn?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding a Firewall exception for the VPN connection did the trick.

Comment: Downvoter please justify your downvote. The firewall exception did help.

Answer (score 2):

Those ports are used by Windows (for Netbios and SMB) and are by default opened *for the local lan only*  in Windows Firewall. (Could be the same on a third-party firewall)

So this it the firewall than block connection to those ports coming from the VPN.

Comment: Windows Firewall is not enabled but a third-party firewall is in use (ESET). This firewall has rules to allow traffic on these ports explicitly.

Comment: Humm then we need more information about your topology. Does this firewall manage a different profile per type of connection? Are you using split tunneling or not on the VPN? Does the machine that connect to the clients computer have a route to the VPN IP Range? etc.. (please edit your original question rather than responding in comment)